# How to avoid CompleteAsync (how to receive messages muliple times)?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I am currently retrieving messages from an Azure Service Bus Topic. Using the example provided by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues), I was able to retrieve and read the message(s) sent to my test topic.

I might seem strange, but I do not wish my message(s) being completed upon retrieval, at least not as long as I am testing my present code. I would like to be able to read those messages again and again and not being required to create and send new messages every time completed a cycle.

The standard code sample mentioned above, states the following

```cs
// Complete the message so that it is not received again.
// This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

I would like to add that I modified the sample a tiny bit:

```cs
namespace CoreReceiverApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

    class Program
    {
        // Connection String for the namespace can be obtained from the Azure portal under the 
        // 'Shared Access policies' section.
        const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "<your_connection_string>";
        const string TopicName = "<your_topic_Name>";
        const string SubscriptionName = "<your_subscription_Name>";
        static ISubscriptionClient subscriptionClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName, SubscriptionName);

            Console.WriteLine("======================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER key to exit after receiving all the messages.");
            Console.WriteLine("======================================================");

            // Register MessageHandler and receive messages in a loop
            RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();
 
            Console.ReadKey();

            await subscriptionClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
        {
            // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.
            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                // Maximum number of Concurrent calls to the callback `ProcessMessagesAsync`, set to 1 for simplicity.
                // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 10,

                // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
                // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
                AutoComplete = false
            };

            // Register the function that will process messages
            subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
        }

        static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // Process the message
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

            // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
            // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
            await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

            // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the queueClient has already been closed.
            // If queueClient has already been Closed, you may chose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc. calls 
            // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
        }

        static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
            var context = exceptionReceivedEventArgs.ExceptionReceivedContext;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception context for troubleshooting:");
            Console.WriteLine($"- Endpoint: {context.Endpoint}");
            Console.WriteLine($"- Entity Path: {context.EntityPath}");
            Console.WriteLine($"- Executing Action: {context.Action}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

So what would be the alternative, or to be a bit more precise, the opposite of `CompleteAsync`?
Is it possible at all, how could I avoid having to create new messages after each run?

Comment: I do not understand why do you have to mark it completed at all then.. Why do you call "CompleteAsync" ?

Comment: Tip: `static async Task Main(string[] args) { await MainAsync(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the peeklock mode to receive message in Azure sdervice bus, the receiving client will initiate settlement of a received message with a positive acknowledgment when it calls `Complete` at the API level. This indicates to the broker that the message has been successfully processed and the message is removed from the queue or subscription. So you want the message to be redelivered, you can elapse lock or use `Abandon` to unlock message. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock)

Comment: Are there any examples for using Abandon apart from its [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.abandon?view=azure-dotnet)? This might be what I am looking for, but I am not sure how to implement that

Comment: @Sasquatch you can just update code `await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);` as `await subscriptionClient.AbandonAsync() `.

Answer (score 3):

I would not advise having your production code altered for debugging purposes. Instead, create a script or a helper program to seed the queue with the necessary messages for your testing/debugging sessions. If you really wish, you could comment out the message completion code (`queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)` but that will shift from one problem to another as you'll have to increase the `MaxDeliveryCount` on the queue to ensure messages are not dead-lettered.

Comment: To be honest, I used to comment out that particular section you referred to, but it felt a bit "wrong" and I had similar thoughts that this might result in other issues. I'll try creating a helper method as you kindly suggested.